# Help with finding a vector, line, and point in 3D space (linear-algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

I'm currently working on a linear algebra problem set and I'm struggling with the following questions:

**a)** Find a vector that is orthogonal to both $(1,1,2)$ and $(-3,4,1)$, and then find an equation for the line that goes through the point $P_0:(0,1,2)$ and has direction $v$.

**b)** Find the point $Q$ on the line from part a) that minimizes the distance between $Q$ and the point $P:(2,3,3)$.

**c)** Find the point $Q$ in the plane $x+2y+z+1=0$ that minimizes the distance between $Q$ and the point $P:(2,3,3)$.

For part a), I know that two vectors are orthogonal if their dot product is $0$, so I tried to find a vector that satisfies this condition. I found the cross product of the given vectors to get $v=(1,1,-1)$, and the line is $P_0(t)=(0,1,2)+t(1,1,-1)$.

For part b), I know that I need to use the shortest distance formula to find the point $Q$, but I'm having trouble setting up the equation to minimize the distance. I found that the point $Q$ on the line $P_0(t)$ that is closest to the point $P=(2,3,3)$ is $Q=(\frac{5}{3},\frac{8}{3},\frac{4}{3})$. Then, the distance between $P$ and the line is $|PQ|=\sqrt{\frac{13}{3}}$.

For part c), I calculated the equation of the line $P(t)=(2,3,3)+t(1,2,1)$ and substituted it into the equation of the plane $x-y+3z=6$ to get $t=\frac{5}{3}$. Then, the intersection point is $P(\frac{5}{3})=(\frac{8}{3},\frac{13}{3},\frac{8}{3})$.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$(-9,-7,7) \cdot (1,1,2)=-9-7+14=-2\neq0$$

is not a correct choice for the orthogonal vector. We can proceed as follows

**Part a)**

By cross product

$$v=(1,1,2)\wedge (-3,4,1)=(7,7,-7)$$

which is the same as $(1,1,-1)$ and the line is $$P_0 (t)=P_0+vt=(0,1,2)+t(1,1,-1)$$

**Part b)**

An effective way is consider and minimize $|P-P_0(t)|^2$ by derivative to find $t_Q$ such that $Q=P_0(t_Q)$.

**Part c)**

A vector normal to the plane in given by $v=(1,2,1)$ then consider the line

$$P(t)=P+vt=(2,3,3)+t(1,2,1)$$

and finally its intersection with the given plane.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and explanation!

For part a), I see now that I made a mistake in calculating the orthogonal vector. Using the cross product, I get $v=(1,1,-1)$, and the line is $P_0(t)=(0,1,2)+t(1,1,-1)$.

For part b), I followed your suggestion and found that the point $Q$ on the line $P_0(t)$ that is closest to the point $P=(2,3,3)$ is $Q=(\frac{5}{3},\frac{8}{3},\frac{4}{3})$. Then, the distance between $P$ and the line is $|PQ|=\sqrt{\frac{13}{3}}$.

Comment: For part c), I calculated the equation of the line $P(t)=(2,3,3)+t(1,2,1)$ and substituted it into the equation of the plane $x-y+3z=6$ to get $t=\frac{5}{3}$. Then, the intersection point is $P(\frac{5}{3})=(\frac{8}{3},\frac{13}{3},\frac{8}{3})$.

Comment: @AFM Well done! You could edit your original question adding all these detail. I'll take a closer look to check it!

Comment: Done as you told!

Comment: @AFM I obtain $|P-P_0(t)|^2=(2-t)^2+(2-t)^2+(1+t)^2$ which leads to $t=1$ with $Q=(1,2,1)$ and distance equal to $2$.

Comment: For part c is not the plane $x+2y+z+1=0$?

Comment: I apologize for the mistake in part b), you are correct that the equation should be $(2-t)^2+(2-t)^2+(1+t)^2=-3t^{2}-6t+9$, which has a minimum at $t=1$ with $Q=(1,2,1)$ and distance $\sqrt{13}$. 

As for part c), you are also correct that the equation of the plane is $x+2y+z+1=0$. Thank you for catching my error. Using this equation and the equation of the line $P(t)=(2,3,3)+t(1,2,1)$, we get the intersection point $P(\frac{-1}{2})=(\frac{3}{2},2,\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: For *part b* we have $(2-t)^2+(2-t)^2+(1+t)^2=3t^{2}-6t+9$ and the distance at $t=1$ should be $\sqrt 6$.

Comment: For part c there is some problem with the intersecion point $\left(\frac{3}{2},2,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ since this one doesn't satisfy the plane equation.

Comment: I apologize for my mistakes. You are correct that the distance in part b) is $\sqrt{6}$ at $t=1$ and the intersection point in part c) does not satisfy the plane equation.

Let me correct part b) first. We have $(2-t)^2+(2-t)^2+(1+t)^2=3t^2-6t+9$, and taking the derivative we get $6t-6=0$, so $t=1$ is the value that minimizes the distance. Plugging in $t=1$, we get $Q=(1,2,1)$ and the distance is $\sqrt{6}$.

Comment: For part c), we have the equation of the plane $x+2y+z+1=0$ and the equation of the line $P(t)=(2,3,3)+t(1,2,1)$. Substituting $P(t)$ into the plane equation, we get

$$(2+t)+2(3+2t)+(3+t)+1=0$$

which simplifies to $t=-2$. Plugging in $t=-2$ into the equation for the line, we get $P(-2)=(0,-1,1)$, which satisfies the equation of the plane $x+2y+z+1=0$, so we can confirm that it is the correct intersection point.

Comment: @AFM Yes now it seems fine! Now you can finally update you question with the correct results.